# How to authenticate on a website having login button with password?

Tags: java, authentication

How can I login on a webpage by just using java code?

The website I want to authenticate with has the following structure:

```
<input type="password" id="password" /> 
<input type="button" id="login" value="Login" />

<script>
 document.cookie = "token=" + token;
</script>
```

It does not have a `form` element, just two input fields: one for the password, and one for the login process. The website itself then encrypts the data using some `JS/AJAX` functions, exchanges a challenge key with the server, and if successfully logged in, sets the `cookie` with the `token` authentication.

How can I trigger this authentication routine on this side from code? So I just get the cookie back and can extract the token for further requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the request via an ajax request and then evaluate the answer from the server with JavaScript.

E.g. if you can use jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some/endpoint.jsp",
    data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );

    // your instructions
    document.cookie = "token=" + token;
});
```

(example from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **AJAX** to check the authentication,
Modify the html as below to call a function when click on the button,

```
<input type="password" id="password" />
<input type="button" id="login" value="Login" onclick="fn_Login();"/>
```

Include jQuery by putting the below mentioned script tag,

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

And create a javaScript function to make the AJAX call on click of the **Login** Button.

```
<script>
function fn_Login(){
     var password_val = $('#password').val();
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "someAction.do",
            data: { password: password_val }
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            document.cookie = "token=" + token;
        });
}
</script>
```